# Async calls with Apollo + Vue

Tags: vue.js, graphql, apollo

Currently, I am trying to fetch data from my server, but the problem that I am running into is that the data takes a little time to fetch(in postman though it is instantaneous), longer than it takes the DOM to get mounted/loaded, and hence I get errors(data not defined) and nothing will load to the DOM.

If I console.log the data after the DOM has finished mounting then I can see it in the console, but I haven't been able to find a workaround where the component waits to render until the data is fetched.

I tried using a v-if statement, and writing it in a few different ways, but I am still getting the errors of the data not being defined, and it does not load either after the query is done fetching. Currently I've set the data to first be equal to null, which in JS is actually an object and it does get filled with the data after the fetching is done. I can see this in the console. Before that I tried a simple v-if="GameWeek", and with GameWeek defined as both an empty object and an empty array, but none of these will work, and force the component to wait until the data is done fetching.

My question is, is there any way to do this asynchronously, or better yet, make the component wait until the data has been fetched and then correctly load it to the DOM?

This is what my component looks like:

```
<template>
    <!--  Highest climber & longest fall -->
    <v-container>
        <v-card class="card-container mx-auto" v-if="GameWeek !== null" :v-for="player in GameWeek" :key="player.player_id">
            <!-- Top part of card -->
             <v-list-item three-line>
                <v-list-item-content>
                    <div class="card_top_section">
                        <v-avatar>
                            <img
                                src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/john.jpg"
                                alt="John"
                            >
                        </v-avatar>
                        <div class="ml-3">
                            <p class="cardText player_name">
                                {{  player.player_name  }}
                            </p>
                            <p class="cardText team_name">
                                {{ player.team_name }}
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="card_divs mt-7">
                        <p class="cardText points">
                        Points this week {{ player.points }}
                        </p>
                       <!--  <p class="points_green points">
                            
                        </p> -->
                    </div>
                   <!--  Second Row Card -->
                    <div class="card_divs bottom_line">
                        <p class="cardText points">
                            Total points {{ player.total }}
                        </p>
                       <!--  <p class="points_green points">
                            
                        </p> -->
                    </div>
                    
                </v-list-item-content>
             </v-list-item>
        </v-card>
    </v-container>      
</template>

<script>
    import gql from 'graphql-tag'
    export default {
        name: 'PlayerCard',
        data: () => {
            return {
                GameWeek: null
            }
        },
        apollo: {
            GameWeek: gql`query GameWeek {
                GameWeek {
                    team_id
                    points
                    player_name
                    rank
                    previous_rank
                    total
                    player_id
                    team_name
                }
            }`
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log('This is the gameweek', this.GameWeek)
        },
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, turns out this was easy to solve once I found the issue.

It was the : infront of the v-for statement. Once that was removed it all worked :)